# cryptozombies why use keccak in comparing

Tags: ethereum

I am already in lesson 2 Chapter 13 of cryptozombies tutorial. In feedAndMultiply function why they use keccak to compare Kitty rather the exact character.

```
if (keccak256(_species) == keccak256("kitty"))
```

why not

```
if (_species == "kitty") ?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `==` operator is only supported for booleans, integers, fixed point numbers (once support for fixed point numbers is launched), addresses, and static byte arrays. Solidity does **not** support `==` for dynamic arrays (which `string` is). To work around this, they are simply taking the hash value of the two strings and then comparing the result.

The [Types page in the Solidity docs](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/types.html) outlines all of the supported operations for each type.